# How to insert a message of 20 mb into Azure Cosmos DB - Document DB API

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a requirement for our application to handle incoming message requests of up to 20 MB in a transaction. This message is well structured and has nested objects and arrays. We are planning to use Azure Cosmos DB (Document DB API) as our database. As Document DB has a limitation of 2 MB as the maximum document size, we have modeled our message data to be stored in several document. We were trying to insert all these documents in a transaction using the Javascript Store Procedure, but the SPs have a size limit (2 MB) on the request size.

Can anyone help us with how we can save all the documents related to the 20 MB message in a transaction (save all or none)?

One way I have come across is to save the documents independently, and write a store procedure to identify and delete them all in case one of the write fails.
I'd like to know if this is the best available approach for our scenario.

**Edit:** Another possible approach I was thinking about - Upload the 20 MB message into a blob storage, and access it from inside the SP to split and insert. But I couldn't find a way to access the blob from the javascript SP (XMLHttpRequest was not allowed in the SP)

Comment: I would contact MS support. They have been known to disable the size limitation on demand for certain cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into Azure Cosmos DB's [attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-resources#attachments-and-media) functionality? That will be a simpler approach than implementing your own transaction semantics. You should store only the properties you need for querying in the document, then store the 20MB full document as an attachment.

Comment: The requirement for us is to be able to query/ parse all of the message data. So store in a blob doesn't look like the most efficient way. Is there a way the documents can be stored in the collection itself?

Comment: I would also add that storing larger documents in Cosmos DB has a hefty impact on performance. So if at all possible, Aravind's suggestion is a good way to go. Take a look at what happens to your RU costs when inserting or reading larger documents - it's brutal.

Comment: it's worth noting [the deprecation notice in the attachements doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/attachments) though